# Drupal 8 добавить атрибут к form > inpunt type="search"

Tags: drupal8

Стандартная форма поиска имеет вид:

```
<form>
    <input type="search">
</form>
```

Как добавить атрибут к input, placeholder="Что будем искать?", чтобы текст был внути формы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хук фром альтер:

```
function konkin_info_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if (in_array($form_id, ['search_block_form', 'search_form'])) {
    $form['keys']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Что будем искать?');
  }
}
```